# Uninstall windows 10 app

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

When debugging a Windows 10 universal app, the application is deployed and saved on local machine. It is also able to store some data locally. How do I completely uninstall the application? I want to be able to try how the application behaves when it is installed for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to the project properties for your app and select the Debug tab. There, you will find a check box called "Uninstall and then re-install my package. All information about the application state is deleted."

Tick the check box, and now every time you deploy your app from Visual Studio it will be uninstalled first.